# Verifying that a string contains only letters in console application in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, console-application

I need to check if my string contains only letters and no numbers. Please NOTICE that i know there is many already posted here on stackoverflow, but none of them helps me because it doesn't use basic functions!

This is my homework, but please help because i cannot solve a problem.

I've done this by using Regex.IsMatch, but teacher told me i can use only basic functions from .net library and use of complex functions like - sorting, searching charaters and things like that is strictly forbidden.

**My code**

```
Console.Write("Enter your name: ");

name = Console.ReadLine();
if (Regex.IsMatch(name, "[^A-Za-z_ŠšČčŽžĆćĐđ]"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("No name entered!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

i have no clue whatsoever, how to do this in other way. So if there is any1body willing to help me or give me a hint, ill be really glad.

Thank you.

Comment: @Yuriy, did you even read my whole post before posting this?

Comment: In c/c++ it would be `if ( !( (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ) ) { /** not an ascii leter **/ }`

Comment: I've looked over the answers here and all of them use supposedly "non-basic" functions or methods.  Surely your teacher has defined what he means by "basic".  Can you reproduce this definition here?  Otherwise, I don't think anyone is going to be able to help out.  Are you allowed to iterate through all the letters of the submission?

Comment: @Cyberherbalist, You can only use charIsLetter if you implement it on your own. Otherwise, bubble sort or ASCII as written under is allowed.

Comment: @sln thank you but i have already sold a problem. Anyway, thank you for your contribution!

Comment: I am confused.  You stated you could only use IsLetter if you implemented it yourself, and could only use basic functions.  And then you accept an answer using IsLetter?  What sense does that make?

Comment: @Cyberherbalist i accepted it because he gave me the right answer in the comments. What else should i accept then?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the comments.  It might be of value if he put his comment in his answer, but that's another matter.  You have now relieved me of my confusion!  Thanks!  It was an interesting question, by the way.

Comment: Yeah well we have to program in this way @ this subject. I just hate it. I'm way better at it when i can use all the functions. Thank you for your time anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`char.IsLetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check  if all the characters in a string are Letter.

```
if (name.All(char.IsLetter))
{
    //All characters are letters
}
```

It is same as:

```
if (name.All(r => char.IsLetter(r)))
```

Comment: it needs to be done with basic functions. char.IsLetter is now allowed

Comment: @fkr, I can give you a hint, Iterate through each character of your string, check if the character's ASCII value is between 48 and 57, If it is, then you got a digit in your string.

Comment: Thank you, i will defo try this.

Comment: This works great but I'd definitely say these are special functions :)

Comment: @DavidKhaykin, I guess the OP meant the logic explained in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316652/verifying-that-a-string-contains-only-letters-in-console-application-in-c-sharp/21316669?noredirect=1#comment32130522_21316669)

Comment: if (checkName[j] > 47 && checkName[j] < 58) ...this is special functions?

Answer (score 0):

Loop the characters and check their ascii value:

```
public Boolean IsAllLetters(String name)
{
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((Int32)name[i] < 65 || ((Int32)name[i] > 90 && (Int32)name[i] < 97) || (Int32)name[i] > 122)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'll offer another approach.  I employ a pair of extension methods to accomplish this, giving me the flexibility to look for any group of characters:

```
public static class StringEx
{
    public static Boolean ContainsOnly(this String theString, String characters)
    {
        return theString.TrimStart(characters.ToCharArray()).Length == 0;
    }

    public static Boolean ContainsOnly(this String theString, Char[] characters)
    {
        return theString.TrimStart(characters).Length == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "i can use only basic functions from .net library and use of complex functions like - sorting, searching charaters and things like that is strictly forbidden." ---> Which means no Contains or TrimStart or any other not basic

Comment: Name[i] < 'a' ... Doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Thanks, edited.  Working from memory...

Answer (score 0):

Not using any special functions:

```
    public void RecognizeOnlyLettersInString()
    {
        string name = "test the 123 thing";
        Console.WriteLine(name);

        string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        foreach (char c in name)
        {
            foreach(char letter in letters)
            {
                if (c == letter)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (letters.IndexOf(letter) == letters.Count() - 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a letter", c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much, but i have already solved the problem by using ASCII that was written by Habib. Thank you so much for the troubles!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see an answer has already been accepted, but it used a function the questioner said he couldn't use, so since I went to the trouble of building an answer, I will put it here for the sake of coming to a conclusion.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] chars = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
bool hasnonletters = false;
for (int x = 0; x < chars.Length; x++)
{
    Console.Write(".");
    int ascii = (int)chars[x];
    if (!((ascii > 64 && ascii < 91) || (ascii > 96 && ascii < 123)))
    {
        hasnonletters = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (hasnonletters)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has Non-letters!", s);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is all letters!", s);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```